# How to find what shutdowns my computer?

Tags: linux-mint, shutdown

```
$ last -x shutdown
shutdown system down  4.15.0-55-generi Sat Aug 10 01:00 - 01:00  (00:00)
...
```

So I'm using my computer and it suddenly shutdowns. I check the log and it exactly shutdowns at 1 am. But I cannot remember any script that I set to shut down my computer at 1 am. So how could I find what shutdowns my computer?

I'm using Linux Mint 19.2.